# HTML form being reloaded and java script message not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new to Javascript programming. I have developed the below script and encountering the below issues. Request the expert to help to resolve the issues.

Issues are

- when both username and password are filled (username not equal to password) the javascript message displays and the form automatically reloads removing the message.
- when username or password is left empty, the message being displayed is "Invalid username or password". The correct javascript message is not being displayed.
- when both the fields are not filled the script executes successfully and "Welcome" is printed. If condition in javascript not being executed to display the correct message. Also have used "required" attribute to display the error "this field is required" but still "welcome' is being printed.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function verify() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ((typeof username) == undefined) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Username Required.";
    }
    
    if ((typeof password) == undefined) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "password Required.";
    }
    
     if (username == password) {
        document.write("Welcome");
        }
     else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Invalid Username or password";
        }
    }
      
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Welcome to MEPC World!!</h1>
    <br>
    <form style="margin:auto;max-width:60%" >
    <fieldset style="border:groove;border-width:5px;border-color:lightgrey;text-align:center">
    <legend><b>Login</b></legend>
      <p id="message" style="color:red;text-align:left"></p>
      <br>
      Username&nbsp;:&nbsp;
      <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username (e.g. XYZ)" autocomplete="off" required="required"> </input>
      <br>
      <br>
      Password&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;
      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" required="required"> </input>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="verify()">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    
    <p><b>Note:</b> Username and password are case-sensitive.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should be doing it. Or the message gets overridden because you have multiple `if` statements instead of an `if/elseif/else` which will only allow one to be `true`.

```
function verify() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (username === undefined || username === '') {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Username Required.";
  }

  else if (password == undefined || password === '') {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "password Required.";
  }
  // This doesn't make sense at all fyi
  else if (username === password) {
    document.write("Welcome");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Invalid Username or password";
  }
}
```

To prevent the form from submitting you have to do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return verify()">
```

Comment: Hello Chrillewoodz, Thanks for your input. your suggestion has helped to resolve the 2 & 3 issue. However I am still facing the 1st issue. When both fields are filled (username/password incorrect) the javascript message displays for a while but the form is again overloaded and message displayed is gone.

Comment: @Harsh I updated answer, now it should solve the 1st issue.